# Assigning values to variables in php

Tags: php, variables

What is the difference between:

```
$recipient = $query_row['email'];
```

and

```
$recipient = 'mine@example.com';
```

where $query_row['email'] is the value returned from a mysql query that works and can be echoed out.

When entered into a function they behave quite differently.

```
$formproc->AddRecipient($recipient);
```

It doesn't work when I use the query returned value, but works fine when I write in an email address to be used. 
Note: $query_row['email'] is the same as mine@example.com

```
print_r($query_row['email']);
```

returns: mine@example.com

```
var_dump($query_row['email']);
```

returns: string(16) "mine@example.com"

When I use  $recipient = 'mine@example.com'; the email is sent to mine@example.com when I use the other method, the email isn't sent.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, show the whole code.

Comment: Does the returned value maybe have extra spaces in it? Or, make sure it is a string.

Comment: print the returned value using `print_r()` OR `var_dump()` to see the exact array structure and value

Comment: I think it could ease the troubleshooting if you further described _how_ they behave differently. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There not any difference in both, both are assigning the value to `$recipient`.

The only difference is `$query_row['email'];` seems to be, you are fetching from the database, where `$recipient = 'mine@example.com';` you are assigning direct.

**Note:** Make sure you has value in `$query_row['email']` and its a string value like `mine@example.com`

Comment: There are can be difference in rare ocasions becouse of specific work of PHP with arrays by references.

Answer (score 1):

`$recipient` could be either a string or integer while `$query_row['email']` is an array, the value `email` belongs to the array called `$query_row`

Answer (score 0):

$query_row['email'] must not equal 'mine@example.com' or $formproc->AddRecipient($recipient) would be returning the same thing. The operands are evaluated before the function call.

In order to give you a more complete answer we would need to see the rest of the code, specifically where $query_row['email'] came from.

Comment: when i do - echo $recipient = $query_row['email']; - I get back mine@example.com in the browser though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you once try with this

$recipient = "'".$query_row['email']."'";

$formproc->AddRecipient($recipient);

and see whether its working or not

Comment: gave it a shot, as well as tried a few alterations with quotes and apostrophes but still nothing.

Comment: Hi once use this normal php mail function and see whether the mail is sending or not I have used this I got the mail..                             $usersquery=mysql_query("select * from users");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($usersquery, MYSQL_BOTH);                     $to=$row['email'];                                                      mail($to, "test", "test");

Comment: use $to=$query_row['email'];                                                  mail($to, "test", "test"); and check whether its working or not..